# flask_sqlalchemy AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'topic1'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, attributeerror

I'm currently developing a Website with flask, and whenever I try to enter my home-page, I get the following error-message:
**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'topic1'**
And apparently the error occurs in this line: found_something.topic1 = topics[x]

These are the relevant parts of my app.py file:

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, sessions
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "zWG3uzYMMrXp3TDYEZBgG4XAfYU4fd"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


db1 = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate()
migrate.init_app(app, db1)

class users(db1.Model):
    username = db1.Column("name", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    password = db1.Column("password", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password


counting = [0]
topics_list = ["found_topic1x.topic1", "found_topic1x.topic2", "found_topic1x.topic3", "found_topic1x.topic4", "found_topic1x.topic5", "found_topic1x.topic6", 
"found_topic1x.topic7", "found_topic1x.topic8", "found_topic1x.topic9", "found_topic1x.topic10", "found_topic1x.topic11", "found_topic1x.topic12", 
"found_topic1x.topic13", "found_topic1x.topic14", "found_topic1x.topic15", "found_topic1x.topic16", "found_topic1x.topic17" "found_topic1x.topic18", 
"found_topic1x.topic19", "found_topic1x.topic20", "found_topic1x.topic21", "found_topic1x.topic22", "found_topic1x.topic23", "found_topic1x.topic24", 
"found_topic1x.topic25", "found_topic1x.topic26", "found_topic1x.topic27", "found_topic1x.topic28", "found_topic1x.topic29",
"found_topic1x.topic30", "found_topic1x.topic31"]


class topics1(db1.Model):
    topicsid = db1.Column("ID", db1.Integer, primary_key=True)
    usernamex = db1.Column("Username", db1.String(100))
    topic1 = db1.Column("Topic 1", db1.String(100))
    topic2 = db1.Column("Topic 2", db1.String(100))
    topic3 = db1.Column("Topic 3", db1.String(100))
    topic4 = db1.Column("Topic 4", db1.String(100))
    topic5 = db1.Column("Topic 5", db1.String(100))
    topic6 = db1.Column("Topic 6", db1.String(100))
    topic7 = db1.Column("Topic 7", db1.String(100))
    topic8 = db1.Column("Topic 8", db1.String(100))
    topic9 = db1.Column("Topic 9", db1.String(100))
    topic10 = db1.Column("Topic 10", db1.String(100))
    topic11 = db1.Column("Topic 11", db1.String(100))
    topic12 = db1.Column("Topic 12", db1.String(100))
    topic13 = db1.Column("Topic 13", db1.String(100))
    topic14 = db1.Column("Topic 14", db1.String(100))
    topic15 = db1.Column("Topic 15", db1.String(100))
    topic16 = db1.Column("Topic 16", db1.String(100))                                             
    topic17 = db1.Column("Topic 17", db1.String(100))
    topic18 = db1.Column("Topic 18", db1.String(100))
    topic19 = db1.Column("Topic 19", db1.String(100))
    topic20 = db1.Column("Topic 20", db1.String(100))
    topic21 = db1.Column("Topic 21", db1.String(100))
    topic22 = db1.Column("Topic 22", db1.String(100))
    topic23 = db1.Column("Topic 23", db1.String(100))
    topic24 = db1.Column("Topic 24", db1.String(100))
    topic25 = db1.Column("Topic 25", db1.String(100))
    topic26 = db1.Column("Topic 26", db1.String(100))
    topic27 = db1.Column("Topic 27", db1.String(100))
    topic28 = db1.Column("Topic 28", db1.String(100))
    topic29 = db1.Column("Topic 29", db1.String(100))
    topic30 = db1.Column("Topic 30", db1.String(100))
    topic31 = db1.Column("Topic 31", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, topicsid, usernamex, topic1, topic2, topic3, topic4, topic5, topic6, topic7, topic8, topic9, topic10, topic11, topic12, topic13, topic14, topic15, topic16,
    topic17, topic18, topic19, topic20, topic21, topic22, topic23, topic24, topic25, topic26, topic27, topic28, topic29, topic30, topic31):

        self.topicsid = topicsid
        self.usernamex = usernamex
        self.topic1 = topic1
        self.topic2 = topic2
        self.topic3 = topic3
        self.topic4 = topic4
        self.topic5 = topic5
        self.topic6 = topic6
        self.topic7 = topic7
        self.topic8 = topic8
        self.topic9 = topic9
        self.topic10 = topic10
        self.topic11 = topic11
        self.topic12 = topic12
        self.topic13 = topic13
        self.topic14 = topic14
        self.topic15 = topic15
        self.topic16 = topic16
        self.topic17 = topic17
        self.topic18 = topic18
        self.topic19 = topic19
        self.topic20 = topic20
        self.topic21 = topic21
        self.topic22 = topic22
        self.topic23 = topic23
        self.topic24 = topic24
        self.topic25 = topic25
        self.topic26 = topic26
        self.topic27 = topic27
        self.topic28 = topic28
        self.topic29 = topic29
        self.topic30 = topic30
        self.topic31 = topic31





class row0(db1.Model):
    username0 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday0 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday0 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday0 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday0 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday0 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username0, Monday0, Tuesday0, Wednesday0, Thursday0, Friday0):
        self.username0 = username0
        self.Monday0 = Monday0
        self.Tuesday0 = Tuesday0
        self.Wednesday0 = Wednesday0
        self.Thursday0 = Thursday0
        self.Friday0 = Friday0



class row1(db1.Model):
    username1 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday1 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday1 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday1 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday1 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday1 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username1, Monday1, Tuesday1, Wednesday1, Thursday1, Friday1):
        self.username1 = username1
        self.Monday1 = Monday1
        self.Tuesday1 = Tuesday1
        self.Wednesday1 = Wednesday1
        self.Thursday1 = Thursday1
        self.Friday1 = Friday1


class row2(db1.Model):
    username2 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday2 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday2 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday2 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday2 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday2 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username2, Monday2, Tuesday2, Wednesday2, Thursday2, Friday2):
        self.username2 = username2
        self.Monday2 = Monday2
        self.Tuesday2 = Tuesday2
        self.Wednesday2 = Wednesday2
        self.Thursday2 = Thursday2
        self.Friday2 = Friday2


class row3(db1.Model):
    username3 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday3 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday3 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday3 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday3 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday3 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username3, Monday3, Tuesday3, Wednesday3, Thursday3, Friday3):
        self.username3 = username3
        self.Monday3 = Monday3
        self.Tuesday3 = Tuesday3
        self.Wednesday3 = Wednesday3
        self.Thursday3 = Thursday3
        self.Friday3 = Friday3



class row4(db1.Model):
    username4 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday4 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday4 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday4 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday4 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday4 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username4, Monday4, Tuesday4, Wednesday4, Thursday4, Friday4):
        self.username4 = username4
        self.Monday4 = Monday4
        self.Tuesday4 = Tuesday4
        self.Wednesday4 = Wednesday4
        self.Thursday4 = Thursday4
        self.Friday4 = Friday4


class row5(db1.Model):
    username5 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday5 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday5 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday5 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday5 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday5 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username5, Monday5, Tuesday5, Wednesday5, Thursday5, Friday5):
        self.username5 = username5
        self.Monday5 = Monday5
        self.Tuesday5 = Tuesday5
        self.Wednesday5 = Wednesday5
        self.Thursday5 = Thursday5
        self.Friday5 = Friday5



class row6(db1.Model):
    username6 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday6 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday6 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday6 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday6 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday6 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username6, Monday6, Tuesday6, Wednesday6, Thursday6, Friday6):
        self.username6 = username6
        self.Monday6 = Monday6
        self.Tuesday6 = Tuesday6
        self.Wednesday6 = Wednesday6
        self.Thursday6 = Thursday6
        self.Friday6 = Friday6



class row7(db1.Model):
    username7 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday7 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday7 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday7 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday7 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday7 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username7, Monday7, Tuesday7, Wednesday7, Thursday7, Friday7):
        self.username7 = username7
        self.Monday7 = Monday7
        self.Tuesday7 = Tuesday7
        self.Wednesday7 = Wednesday7
        self.Thursday7 = Thursday7
        self.Friday7 = Friday7




class row8(db1.Model):
    username8 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday8 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday8 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday8 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday8 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday8 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username8, Monday8, Tuesday8, Wednesday8, Thursday8, Friday8):
        self.username8 = username8
        self.Monday8 = Monday8
        self.Tuesday8 = Tuesday8
        self.Wednesday8 = Wednesday8
        self.Thursday8 = Thursday8
        self.Friday8 = Friday8


class row9(db1.Model):
    username9 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday9 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday9 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday9 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday9 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday9 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username9, Monday9, Tuesday9, Wednesday9, Thursday9, Friday9):
        self.username9 = username9
        self.Monday9 = Monday9
        self.Tuesday9 = Tuesday9
        self.Wednesday9 = Wednesday9
        self.Thursday9 = Thursday9
        self.Friday9 = Friday9

class row10(db1.Model):
    username10 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday10 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday10 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday10 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday10 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday10 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username10, Monday10, Tuesday10, Wednesday10, Thursday10, Friday10):
        self.username10 = username10
        self.Monday10 = Monday10
        self.Tuesday10 = Tuesday10
        self.Wednesday10 = Wednesday10
        self.Thursday10 = Thursday10
        self.Friday10 = Friday10


class row11(db1.Model):
    username11 = db1.Column("username", db1.String(100), primary_key=True)
    Monday11 = db1.Column("Monday", db1.String(100))
    Tuesday11 = db1.Column("Tuesday", db1.String(100))
    Wednesday11 = db1.Column("Wednesday", db1.String(100))
    Thursday11 = db1.Column("Thursday", db1.String(100))
    Friday11 = db1.Column("Friday", db1.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username11, Monday11, Tuesday11, Wednesday11, Thursday11, Friday11):
        self.username11 = username11
        self.Monday11 = Monday11
        self.Tuesday11 = Tuesday11
        self.Wednesday11 = Wednesday11
        self.Thursday11 = Thursday11
        self.Friday11 = Friday11


topics_count = []


@app.route("/home")
def home():
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        found_topics0 = row0.query.filter_by(username0 = user).all()
        found_topics1 = row1.query.filter_by(username1 = user).all()
        found_topics2 = row2.query.filter_by(username2 = user).all()
        found_topics3 = row3.query.filter_by(username3 = user).all()
        found_topics4 = row4.query.filter_by(username4 = user).all()
        found_topics5 = row5.query.filter_by(username5 = user).all()
        found_topics6 = row6.query.filter_by(username6 = user).all()
        found_topics7 = row7.query.filter_by(username7 = user).all()
        found_topics8 = row8.query.filter_by(username8 = user).all()
        found_topics9 = row9.query.filter_by(username9 = user).all()
        found_topics10 = row10.query.filter_by(username10 = user).all()
        found_topics11 = row11.query.filter_by(username11 = user).all()
        found_topic0 = row0.query.all()
        found_topic1 = row1.query.all()
        found_topic2 = row2.query.all()
        found_topic3 = row3.query.all()
        found_topic4 = row4.query.all()
        found_topic5 = row5.query.all()
        found_topic6 = row6.query.all()
        found_topic7 = row7.query.all()
        found_topic8 = row8.query.all()
        found_topic9 = row9.query.all()
        found_topic10 = row10.query.all()
        found_topic11 = row11.query.all()

        
        topics = []

        for x0 in found_topics0:
            if x0.Monday0 not in topics and x0.Monday0 != "":
                topics.append(x0.Monday0)
            if x0.Tuesday0 not in topics and x0.Tuesday0 != "":
                topics.append(x0.Tuesday0)
            if x0.Wednesday0 not in topics and x0.Wednesday0 != "":
                topics.append(x0.Wednesday0)
            if x0.Thursday0 not in topics and x0.Thursday0 != "":
                topics.append(x0.Thursday0)
            if x0.Friday0 not in topics and x0.Friday0 != "":
                topics.append(x0.Friday0)

        for x1 in found_topics1:
            if x1.Monday1 not in topics and x1.Monday1 != "":
                topics.append(x1.Monday1)
            if x1.Tuesday1 not in topics and x1.Tuesday1 != "":
                topics.append(x1.Tuesday1)
            if x1.Wednesday1 not in topics and x1.Wednesday1 != "":
                topics.append(x1.Wednesday1)
            if x1.Thursday1 not in topics and x1.Thursday1 != "":
                topics.append(x1.Thursday1)
            if x1.Friday1 not in topics and x1.Friday1 != "":
                topics.append(x1.Friday1)

        for x2 in found_topics2:
            if x2.Monday2 not in topics and x2.Monday2 != "":
                topics.append(x2.Monday2)
            if x2.Tuesday2 not in topics and x2.Tuesday2 != "":
                topics.append(x2.Tuesday2)
            if x2.Wednesday2 not in topics and x2.Wednesday2 != "":
                topics.append(x2.Wednesday2)
            if x2.Thursday2 not in topics and x2.Thursday2 != "":
                topics.append(x2.Thursday2)
            if x2.Friday2 not in topics and x2.Friday2 != "":
                topics.append(x2.Friday2)


        for x3 in found_topics3:
            if x3.Monday3 not in topics and x3.Monday3 != "":
                topics.append(x3.Monday3)

            if x3.Tuesday3 not in topics and x3.Monday3 != "":
                topics.append(x3.Tuesday3)

            if x3.Wednesday3 not in topics  and x3.Wednesday3 != "":
                topics.append(x3.Wednesday3)

            if x3.Thursday3 not in topics and x3.Thursday3 != "":
                topics.append(x3.Thursday3)

            if x3.Friday3 not in topics and x3.Friday3 != "":
                topics.append(x3.Friday3)

        for x4 in found_topics4:
            if str(x4.Monday4) not in topics and x4.Monday4 != "":
                topics.append(x4.Monday4)
            if x4.Tuesday4 not in topics and x4.Tuesday4 != "":
                topics.append(x4.Tuesday4)
            if x4.Wednesday4 not in topics  and x4.Wednesday4 != "":
                topics.append(x4.Wednesday4)
            if x4.Thursday4 not in topics and x4.Thursday4 != "":
                topics.append(x4.Thursday4)
            if x4.Friday4 not in topics  and x4.Friday4 != "":
                topics.append(x4.Friday4)

        for x5 in found_topics5:
            if x5.Monday5 not in topics and x5.Monday5 != "":
                topics.append(x5.Monday5)
            if x5.Tuesday5 not in topics and x5.Tuesday5 != "":
                topics.append(x5.Tuesday5)
            if x5.Wednesday5 not in topics and x5.Wednesday5 != "":
                topics.append(x5.Wednesday5)
            if x5.Thursday5 not in topics and x5.Thursday5 != "":
                topics.append(x5.Thursday5)
            if x5.Friday5 not in topics and x5.Friday5 != "":
                topics.append(x5.Friday5)

        
        for x6 in found_topics6:
            if x6.Monday6 not in topics and x6.Monday6 != "":
                topics.append(x6.Monday6)
            if x6.Tuesday6 not in topics and x6.Tuesday6 != "":
                topics.append(x6.Tuesday6)
            if x6.Wednesday6 not in topics and x6.Wednesday6 != "":
                topics.append(x6.Wednesday6)
            if x6.Thursday6 not in topics and x6.Thursday6 != "":
                topics.append(x6.Thursday6)
            if x6.Friday6 not in topics and x6.Friday6 != "":
                topics.append(x6.Friday6)

        for x7 in found_topics7:
            if x7.Monday7 not in topics and x7.Monday7 != "":
                topics.append(x7.Monday7)
            if x7.Tuesday7 not in topics and x7.Tuesday7 != "":
                topics.append(x7.Tuesday7)
            if x7.Wednesday7 not in topics and x7.Wednesday7 != "":
                topics.append(x7.Wednesday7)
            if x7.Thursday7 not in topics and x7.Thursday7 != "":
                topics.append(x7.Thursday7)
            if x7.Friday7 not in topics and x7.Friday7 != "":
                topics.append(x7.Friday7)


        for x8 in found_topics8:
            if x8.Monday8 not in topics and x8.Monday8 != "":
                topics.append(x8.Monday8)
            if x8.Tuesday8 not in topics and x8.Tuesday8 != "":
                topics.append(x8.Tuesday8)
            if x8.Wednesday8 not in topics and x8.Wednesday8 != "":
                topics.append(x8.Wednesday8)
            if x8.Thursday8 not in topics and x8.Thursday8 != "":
                topics.append(x8.Thursday8)
            if x8.Friday8 not in topics and x8.Friday8 != "":
                topics.append(x8.Friday8)


        for x9 in found_topics9:
            if x9.Monday9 not in topics and x9.Monday9 != "":
                topics.append(x9.Monday9)
            if x9.Tuesday9 not in topics and x9.Tuesday9 != "":
                topics.append(x9.Tuesday9)
            if x9.Wednesday9 not in topics and x9.Wednesday9 != "":
                topics.append(x9.Wednesday9)
            if x9.Thursday9 not in topics and x9.Thursday9 != "":
                topics.append(x9.Thursday9)
            if x9.Friday9 not in topics and x9.Friday9 != "":
                topics.append(x9.Friday9)


        for x10 in found_topics10:
            if x10.Monday10 not in topics and x10.Monday10 != "":
                topics.append(x10.Monday10)
            if x10.Tuesday10 not in topics and x10.Tuesday10 != "":
                topics.append(x10.Tuesday10)
            if x10.Wednesday10 not in topics and x10.Wednesday10 != "":
                topics.append(x10.Wednesday10)
            if x10.Thursday10 not in topics and x10.Thursday10 != "":
                topics.append(x10.Thursday10)
            if x10.Friday10 not in topics and x10.Friday10 != "":
                topics.append(x10.Friday10)

        for x11 in found_topics11:
            if x11.Monday11 not in topics and x11.Monday11 != "":
                topics.append(x11.Monday11)
            if x11.Tuesday11 not in topics and x11.Tuesday11 != "":
                topics.append(x11.Tuesday11)
            if x11.Wednesday11 not in topics and x11.Wednesday11 != "":
                topics.append(x11.Wednesday11)
            if x11.Thursday11 not in topics and x11.Thursday11 != "":
                topics.append(x11.Thursday11)
            if x11.Friday11 not in topics and x11.Friday11 != "":
                topics.append(x11.Friday11)

        
        top = topics1(counting[-1] + 1, user, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r","s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", 
        "ä", "ö", "ü", "ab", "ac")
        found_something = topics1.query.filter_by(usernamex = user).all()
        if found_something:
            db1.session.add(top)
            db1.session.commit()
            counting.append(counting[-1] + 1)
        found_topic1x = topics1.query.all()


        for x in range(0, len(topics)):
            if x == 0:
                found_something.topic1 = topics[x]
            if x == 1:
                found_something.topic2 = topics[x]
            if x == 2:
                found_something.topic3 = topics[x]
            if x == 3:
                found_something.topic4 = topics[x]
            if x == 4:
                found_something.topic5 = topics[x]
            if x == 5:
                found_something.topic6 = topics[x]
            if x == 6:
                found_something.topic7 = topics[x]
            if x == 7:
                found_something.topic8 = topics[x]
            if x == 8:
                found_something.topic9 = topics[x]
            if x == 9:
                found_something.topic10 = topics[x]
            if x == 10:
                found_something.topic11 = topics[x]
            if x == 11:
                found_something.topic12 = topics[x]
            if x == 12:
                found_something.topic13 = topics[x]
            if x == 13:
                found_something.topic14 = topics[x]
            if x == 14:
                found_something.topic15 = topics[x]
            if x == 15:
                found_something.topic16 = topics[x]
            if x == 16:
                found_something.topic17 = topics[x]
            if x == 17:
                found_something.topic18 = topics[x]
            if x == 18:
                found_something.topic19 = topics[x]
            if x == 19:
                found_something.topic20 = topics[x]
            if x == 20:
                found_something.topic21 = topics[x]
            if x == 21:
                found_something.topic22 = topics[x]
            if x == 22:
                found_something.topic23 = topics[x]
            if x == 23:
                found_something.topic24 = topics[x]
            if x == 24:
                found_something.topic25 = topics[x]
            if x == 25:
                found_something.topic26 = topics[x]
            if x == 26:
                found_something.topic27 = topics[x]
            if x == 27:
                found_something.topic28 = topics[x]
            if x == 28:
                found_something.topic29 = topics[x]
            if x == 29:
                found_something.topic30 = topics[x]
            if x == 30:
                found_something.topic31 = topics[x]


            db1.session.commit()

        

        return render_template("home.html", topics=topics, count=len(topics), found_topic0=found_topic0, found_topic1=found_topic1, found_topic2=found_topic2, 
        found_topic3=found_topic3, found_topic4=found_topic4, found_topic5=found_topic5, found_topic6=found_topic6, found_topic7=found_topic7, found_topic8=found_topic8, 
        found_topic9=found_topic9, found_topic10=found_topic10, found_topic11=found_topic11, user=user, found_topic1x = found_topic1x, topics_list=topics_list)

    else: 
        flash("Sie müssen sich erst einloggen!")
        return redirect(url_for("login"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db1.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True, port=5002)
```

the user in session stores the username.

And this is my "home.html" file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Home {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    {% for x in range(0, count) %}
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-heading{{x}}">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapse{{x}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
          <strong>{{topics[x]}}</strong>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="flush-collapse{{x}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">Gemeinsame Kursteilnehmer: 
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <p><h1>{{topics}}</h1></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help on solving this error is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`found_something` is populated when you use the code: `topics1.query.filter_by(usernamex = user).all()`

So, as it is evident here, found_something is a **list**. Now, to **access individual objects from the list** `found_something`, you must **pass the index**.

Therefore, `found_something[0].topic1` **instead of** `found_something.topic1` will give you the result for **first object** from the list.

Similarly, `found_something[1].topic2` **instead of** `found_something.topic2` will give you the result for **second object**. So on and so forth..